# Conversion Calculator, problems with results.. random answers that aren't correct?

Tags: java

Okay, I'm having a problem with the overall finished product, I'm new to this so I can't spot where I've gone wrong. I enter my conversion type ex: 1 (inches-cm) say i want to know how much cm 5 inches is and it will result in saying: 12.7 cm = 55.0 ? makes 0 sense to me why it is doing that and any help would be awesome!

```
switch(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())){  
case 1:
InchesToCm();
break;
case 2:
CmToFeet();
break;
case 3:
MetresToYards();
break;
case 4:
KmToMetres();
break;
default:
jLabel8.setText("Error, try again");
break;

}








}                                        


private void InchesToCm() {
 double inches, centimetres;   //identify variables
String messageOut;

inches = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());          //get the text
centimetres = (inches*2.54);                                 //preform   
messageOut = centimetres + "cm = " + Math.round(inches) + inches;    //msg
jLabel8.setText(messageOut);
 } 
private void CmToFeet() {
double feet, centimetres;
String messageOut;

feet = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
centimetres = (feet*30);
messageOut = centimetres + "cm = " + Math.round(feet) + feet;
jLabel8.setText(messageOut);

}
private void MetresToYards() {
double metres, yards;
String messageOut;

yards = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
metres = (yards*0.91);
messageOut = metres + "m = " + Math.round(yards) + yards;
jLabel8.setText(messageOut);
}
private void KmToMetres() {
double miles, kilometres;
String messageOut;

miles = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
kilometres = (miles*1.6);
messageOut = kilometres + "km = " + Math.round(miles) + miles;
jLabel8.setText(messageOut);
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you are just concatenating the two inches at the end. Specifically here "Math.round(inches) + inches;". Try swapping it to Math.round(inches) + "inches";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the `inches` variable twice in a row and confusing yourself.  The `Math.round` return value is responsible for the `5`, and the printing of `inches` itself (a `double`) is responsible for the `5.0`.  Concatenated, it reads `55.0`.  I suspect you wanted the *string* `"inches"` printed instead:

```
messageOut = centimetres + "cm = " + Math.round(inches) + " inches";
```

Similar changes should be made on the other methods.